# Is there a way to jump to last edited cell in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Often in Jupyter I'd move to different parts of the notebook to look at something, and when I am done I want to jump back to where I was working on previously. Right now I'd have to navigate to the closest Markdown section (through the Jupyter Notebook Extensions) and move up or down to get to where I was. Is there a way to jump directly to the last cell that I have made an edit (preferably through keyboard shortcut)? Thanks!

Comment: In JupyterLab you can use [jupyterlab-lsp](https://github.com/jupyter-lsp/jupyterlab-lsp) extension which has "Jump to" function, and a corresponding "Jump back" function, both are bound to customizable shortcuts. Not adding as an answer since the tag is "Jupyter Notebook" and not "Jupyter" or "JupyterLab".

Answer (score 1):

Ideally this would be a built-in shortcut of course, but in the meantime:

##### Option 1: Custom JavaScript

If you get a browser extension like [Custom JavaScript for Websites 2](https://github.com/xcv58/Custom-JavaScript-for-Websites-2) (open-source), then you can use this code to record a stack of scroll position histories and jump backwards with `Ctrl+Shift+X`:

```js
// Visit JupyterLab in browser and click the Custom JS browser extension icon and then paste this:
if(location.href.startsWith("http://localhost:8888/lab")) {
  let scrollLocationsHistories = new Map();
  let scrollBinHeight = 100;
  window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    let notebookEl = document.querySelector(".jp-mod-searchable .jp-NotebookPanel-notebook");
    if(!scrollLocationsHistories.has(notebookEl)) scrollLocationsHistories.set(notebookEl, [])
    let scrollLocationsHistory = scrollLocationsHistories.get(notebookEl);
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === "X") {
      if(scrollLocationsHistory.length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let origScrollPos = notebookEl.scrollTop;
        notebookEl.scrollTo(0, scrollLocationsHistory.pop()*scrollBinHeight);
        let newScrollPos = notebookEl.scrollTop;
        if(Math.abs(origScrollPos-newScrollPos) < scrollBinHeight && scrollLocationsHistory.length > 0) {
          notebookEl.scrollTo(0, scrollLocationsHistory.pop()*scrollBinHeight); // jump back again because last edit position was close to current position
        } 
        console.log("Scroll History (newest locations at end):", scrollLocationsHistory.map(v => v*scrollBinHeight))
      }
    } else if(!e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey && document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === "textarea") {
      let scrollBin = Math.round(notebookEl.scrollTop/scrollBinHeight);
      if(scrollLocationsHistory[scrollLocationsHistory.length-1] !== scrollBin) {
        scrollLocationsHistory.push(scrollBin);
        if(scrollLocationsHistory.length > 500) scrollLocationsHistory = scrollLocationsHistory.slice(-250);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

It's just an initial prototype, but it seems to work quite well so far. You may want to adjust it a bit - e.g. `scrollBinHeight` causes nearby edits that are within `scrollBinHeight` pixels of one another to not create a second history entry. You'll need to edit `http://localhost:8888/lab` to match the URL that you want to enable it on. If you're reading this long after I've written it, then you may also need to change `document.querySelector(".jp-mod-searchable .jp-NotebookPanel-notebook")` (i.e. the main scrolling element of the active notebook) in case they've updated the HTML class names, or HTML structure.

##### Option 2: Fold Often

Another possible option (which may be impractical depending on your use case) is to get used to folding cells that you're not currently working on. That makes it much easy to quickly scroll between cells that you're working on.

##### Option 3: Search Hack

If you're working on a particular cell but often have to jump to another one, you can add a comment like `#vv` (or any random easy-to-type string) to both of those cells and then whenever you need to jump between them, just press `Ctrl+F` and then `Enter`. The first time you do this you'll obviously need to type `vv` in the search box, but after that it'll be remembered (unless you use the search for another string). The disadvantage of this approach is that you need to "prune" the `#vv`s from cells that you're no longer working on.

Answer (score -1):

`echap` to go to command mode, then `Ctrl` + `z` will undo your last change, which will bring the focus on the last edited cell. `ctrl` + `y` will redo the last modification.

(Only tested on python3 kernel)

**EDIT** Actually if you press `ctrl` + `z` just once, you only get the focus part, without modifying your cell. Then press `enter` to go to edit mode, which scrolls the page to the active cell.

Comment: it didn't work on jupyter lab or jupyter tree. ctrl + z only works to undo the edit on the currently selected. it will not jump to the last edited cell. even if did undo the last edited cell, i don't think it will jump to it... as the undo happens silently.. far away down the page.. this has been my experience and observation... there is no solution for this in the jupyter notebook yet as far as i know. for example in microsoft word shift + f5 takes you to the last place in the document.